# express.js like urls in Django

Tags: django, url, configuration, express

can we use express.js like url configuration in django ?, sometimes using regex is would be a huge pain !

express.js urls:

```
app.get('/users/:id/feed',function(){})
```

django urls:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<id>.*)/feed$', 'users.views.feed')
```

i think the express's url conf is too simplier than django's. it would be nice use urls in django like this, looking good:

```
url('/users/:id/feed', 'users.views.feed')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a simpler url structure in Django you would need to write a utility function that converts your url format into regular expression format.

Here is a simple function based on your example:

```
def easy_url(url_str):
    patt = re.compile(r':\w+/?')
    matches = patt.findall(url_str)
    for match in matches:
        var = match[1:-1]
        # generate re equivalent 
        var_re = r'(?P<%s>\w+)/'%var
        url_str = url_str.replace(match, var_re) 
    url_str += '$'
    return url_str

# in your url file
url(easy_url('/users/:id/feed/'), 'users.views.feed')
```

You can update this function to specify types for url variables e.g. numbers only etc.

However, regular expressions are very powerful and you can do so many things with them. So you should use such wrapper only for urls with simple rules to keep it lightweight.

Comment: No problem. I think you can simplify a lot of common urls to use an easy url structure like the one you mentioned. Also, this should work if you have multiple parameters, e.g. /users/:id/feed/:cat/

Answer (score 2):

In the core Django you can only specify urls using regex expressions.

I am not familiar with express.js however by using regex, you can do some cool things like:

- positional and named parameters

  ```
  # named
  url(r'^(?P<foo>.*)/(?P<foo2>.*)/$', 'view', name='view')

  # corresponds to
  # something does not have to be supplied
  def view(request, something=None, foo=None, foo2=None)
      ...
  ```

  and

  ```
  # positional
  url(r'^(.*)/(.*)/$', 'view', name='view')

  # corresponds to
  # all groups in regex are supplied in the same order (positions)
  def view(request, foo, foo2)
      ...
  ```
- calculate reverse urls

  ```
  # with
  url(r'^some/path/(?P<foo>.*)/(?P<foo2>.*)/$', 'view', name='view')

  >>> reverse('view', kwargs={'foo':'hello', 'foo2':'world'})
  u'some/path/hello/world/'
  ```
- restrict urls

  ```
  url(r'^some/path/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'view', name='view')
  # will only allow urls like
  # some/path/5/
  # some/path/10/

  # and will reject
  # some/path/hello/
  # some/path/world/
  ```

Comment: yes, you're right using regex is too much advanced, but i want simplier solution, thanks for the patterns